# Installation of RSpectra within R 3.4.1 on CentOS 7

Tags: r, centos

I'm trying to install the R RSpectra package on a CentOS 7 installation. I am running into a message from the assembler.

I have tried to install both the RSpectra_0.12-0.tar.gz and RSpectra_0.11-0.tar.gz, with the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
# rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64

# R
> R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"
> install.packages("RSpectra")
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN/src/contrib/RSpectra_0.12-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 426762 bytes (416 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 416 KB

* installing *source* package ‘RSpectra’ ...
** package ‘RSpectra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/RcppEigen/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c eigs_gen.cpp -o eigs_gen.o
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:284792: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make: *** [eigs_gen.o] Error 4
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RSpectra’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RSpectra’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpwyAGGH/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("RSpectra") :
  installation of package ‘RSpectra’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Comment: As clearly stated in the error message, this is an internal compiler error, and nothing to do with R or RSpectra. 

Also, how on earth did you end up with such a strange package compilation command......did you compile R yourself?

Comment: Thanks!  No, I'm not doing anything fancy. This is the command line generated for installing the package RSpectra. 

I agree the g++ compiler is at fault. I've been able to compile RSpectra on a mac.  I've independently verified both the code and the compiler on different code. So it looks like a compatibility issue.  

I

Comment: My solution was to change from CentOS to Ubuntu. This switch has allowed me to successfully load this and other R libraries with little trouble.